# Changing delay with NOT gate?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I just asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45886/activating-one-piston-while-deactivating-another-at-the-same-time) 30 minutes ago and was told to use a NOT gate

It worked at first, but I had to delay one of the pistons 100%. The problem is when they are to go back to the starting layout, to get it right I have to delay the second piston instead of the first. Is there any way to fix this without using several levers? Is changing the delay possible or are there any other options?

Comment: http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Repeater

Comment: @badp that's not quite what he means. Jkguitar, I know what you're trying to do. A while back I designed a circuit to do exactly that. I'm at work right now, but I'll try to create a diagram of the circuit later.

Comment: Oh geez. I ended up hardly being home this weekend, and forgot to make the diagram :( I'll try to remember to do it tonight.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use a pulse extender. While I can't be perfectly sure how, since I don't know exactly what you're doing, I can give you an example on how to use one. Here I have a simple piston circuit:

[image]

When you flick the lever, it moves the dirt block up:

[image]

The magic occurs when you flip the lever back down. The dirt will return to its original position, and the pistons sync up. The way it works is simple. It makes the bottom (pushing up) piston delayed a little, and it makes the side piston start quickly but stay on longer when you turn it off.

The repeater leading to the bottom piston is straightforward, it will just delay the piston a few ticks to wait for the other piston. The other set it slightly more complex:

[image]

The set of two repeaters is what actually extends the pulse. The 1-tick repeater goes through quickly, so the piston will turn on quickly. The 4-tick repeater goes through takes more time, so it will keep the piston on after the lever is turned off, and the piston will retract more slowly.

The third repeater in this image is simply there to prevent a small Minecraft bug. If you take it out, the piston will quickly retract and push out again when the 4-tick piston is powered, even though the wire is still powered correctly. Placing an additional repeater stabilizes this signal, keeping the piston extended.

Comment: _Offtopic_: is this Faithful texture-pack?

Comment: @MyFaJoArCo: Yes, yes it is.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear before here's a video of what im trying to build. When I built up an example it worked to my suprise but when i tried to build it the same way where it were supposed to be in the beggining. Even if i can se no differenc between the to constructions one of them work and the other doesn't. Both examples are in the video. http://youtu.be/50sAG3Lqx8k

Answer (score 1):

Use Repeaters to change the delay.